videojs - No compatible source was found for this media in wordpress app
There is an issue appearing of  video.js showing compatiablity issues, but when clicking on the video the video works, checking the server as well there is no codecs issue, also checked h.264 encoding that is also there, is there any other issue that can cause this? apologize cannot share app/server details
https://www.vyjou.com/negozio/tronchetti-e-stivaletti/molly-mocassino-in-vera-pelle-cuoio-con-accessorio/



